# Draw in FrameBuffer

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, libgdx

I work with a program which draws some 2D textures and work with them. In this program was used libgdx. I have some problem with using FrameBuffer. I try draw some texture in my FrameBuffer and after that I need save changed texture(or draw) and use this texture in this FrameBuffer on more time. I try save texture via

```
Texture texture = mFrameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture()
```

and I try just bind texture from FrameBuffer

```
mFilterBuffer.getColorBufferTexture().bind();
```

For first iteration all work good. But when I try use in FrameBuffer his ColorBufferTexture like texture I have fully black texture.
Code:

```
public void process(MySprite psObject, float startX, float startY, 
float endX, float endY, int mWidth, int mHeight) {
         boolean frst = false;
         if(psObject.getFrameBuffer() == null){
             psObject.setFrameBuffer(new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888,     psObject.getTexture().getWidth(), psObject.getTexture().getHeight(), true));
         }
         if(pSprite == null || pSprite != psObject){
             mFrameBuffer = psObject.getFrameBuffer();
             frst = true;
             pSprite = psObject;
         }
         mFrameBuffer.begin();
         Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, psObject.getTexture().getWidth(), psObject.getTexture().getHeight());
         Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
         Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
         ShaderProgram shader = MyUtils.newInstance().getCurrentShader();
         if(!shader.isCompiled()){
             Log.i("ERROR", "SHERROR " + shader.getLog());
         }
         if(shader != null){
             if(frst){
                 psObject.getTexture().bind();
             }else{
       mFrameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture().bind();
             }
             shader.begin();
             Matrix4 matrix = new Matrix4();
             matrix.setToRotation(1, 0, 0, 180);
             matrix.scale(scaleSizeInFilterProcessor, scaleSizeInFilterProcessor, 1);
             shader.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView", matrix);
             shader.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);
             float [] start = new float[]{0f,0};
             float [] end = new float[]{1f,1f};
             MyUtils.newInstance().getShaderData(shader, start, end, mWidth, mHeight);
             psObject.getMesh().render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
             shader.end();
         }
         mFrameBuffer.end();
     }
```

Comment: how often do you call the function "process"? When you call the function the first time in the programm, what value do you have for "pSprite"? What's your shaders source code? Even if there don't occure any errors, a shader could still be responsible for a black screen. Did you test the scene you want to render by using a white texture or something like that? There a still some questions about your issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs some refactoring ;). Anyway, you can't read and write from/to the same FBO if that's your question.
You'll need 2 FBO's (say A and B)

```
Draw scene to A,
Bind A's color texture
Draw scene to B (now you can read from A).
```

Note that you can extend libgdx FBO to have many textures associated with the same FBO.